# How to pick the most recent record from sql table among multiple records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have developed a website which facilitates a LAWYER to enter **CASE DETAILS** along with **NEXT HEARING DATES**. Each case can have more than 1 **HEARING DATES**. Let's assume we have **3 CASES** in table with each having multiple hearing dates but I want to pick most **last** **HEARING DATE** of each case then how I should go for it ?

I have used `TOP` then `MAX` with `select statement` but nothing worked.

What I am stroing are:

```
pk_Cases_CaseID
CaseNo
CaseTitle
CaseRemarks
CaseNextHearingDate
IsCaseFinalized
CaseEntryDateTime
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL which you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, the typical method would be to use `row_number()`.  Your question doesn't really explain what the data layout is (the column names seem quite different from the description).  However, the logic looks like:

```
select h.*
from (select h.*,
             row_number() over (partition by caseno order by hearingdate desc) as seqnum
      from hearings h
     ) h
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on using Top and Max, I'm assuming you might be missing some grouping logic. This is assuming the CaseNo is the same for the different rows.

```
  select 
         CaseNo, Max(CaseNextHearingDate)
  from 
         CaseTable
  GROUP BY 
         CaseNo
```

Comment: yes sir, caseno remaing same for on going case and new number for another case and so on. Case no is alpha numeric